# How can i get the path from where gulp was run?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm building a frontend workflow with gulp where i need to be able to build multiple separate designs but they need to share some common settings.

To clarify, i have a structure like this:

- [Project root]

  - Templates

    - Designs

      - MyDesign1

        - Assets

          - js

            - *.js*
          - scss

            - .scss
        - gulpfile.js
      - MyDesign2

        - Assets

          - js

            - *.js*
          - scss

            - .scss
        - gulpfile.js
      - [More designs can be added later]
  - .eslintrc (Shared)
  - sftp-config.json (Shared)

I'd like to be able to call `gulp` in `templates/designs/mydesign1` or `templates/designs/mydesign2` and have acess to the data inside `[Project root]/sftp-config.json` and `[Project root]/.eslintrc` and any other file that might exist outside of the folder that gulp was run from.

Is that possible?

Comment: How about keeping just one gulpfile in the root folder. You can always run commands in specific directories?

Comment: Having only one gulpfile would mean that i need to have a unique task names for each designs folder.

Comment: Then use that root gulp file to execute the folder specific files as shell commands. In any case it is one or the same thing - have unique files for each folder or have unique tasks for each folder in the same file.

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution to my problem, and it seems to work pretty well for my needs:

By using `process.cwd()` i can get the folder that gulp ran in, and then i can use `path.resolve('../')` to step back in my folders until i hit my project root folder.

```
var gulpRanInThisFolder = process.cwd();
var rootDir = path.resolve('../','../','../','../');
var designFolderName = pkg.name;
var sftpConfigPath =  path.join(rootDir, '/sftp-config.json');
```

Comment: To clarify, `process.cwd()` returns the directory you are running the script from, not the directory in which gulp resides. "The folder that gulp ran in" is a bit ambiguous :) 

`__dirname` would get you the folder in which gulp resides.